# Excel insert a cell value into a function and return the new value (not the formula)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that will overwrite all the values in a column by inserting them into a function and then pasting in the result. When I try this my function thinks the inserted variable is text, not a variable. I am not sure how to make it recognize it as a variable. 
The cell is always in the format 12345-6789, I am trying to make it return the value 12345. However, the cell ends up with the value =Clean_Zip(cell.Value) instead of inserting the formula, running it and pulling out the returned value.

```
Sub FixItUp()

Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range


LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("F5:F" & LastRow)

For Each cell In rng
    cell.Value = "=Clean_Zip(cell.Value)"
Next cell

End Sub




Public Function Clean_Zip(ZipCode)

'Function formats all zipcodes to a 5 digit number & converts text values to 
 number values

ZipCode = Trim(ZipCode)
Select Case countNumbers(ZipCode)

    Case Is <= 99
        Clean_Zip = "Error"
    Case Is <= 999
        Clean_Zip = "00" & countNumbers(ZipCode)
    Case Is <= 9999
        Clean_Zip = "0" & countNumbers(ZipCode)
    Case Is <= 999999
        Clean_Zip = Left(ZipCode, 5)
    Case Is <= 99999999
        Clean_Zip = "0" & Left(ZipCode, 4)
    Case Is <= 999999999
        Clean_Zip = Left(ZipCode, 5)

    Case countNumbers(ZipCode)
       Clean_Zip = countNumbers(ZipCode)

    If InStr(5, ZipCode, " ") Then
        Clean_Zip = Left(ZipCode, 5)
    End If

End Select
End Function




Public Function countNumbers(Cell)

If Left(Cell, 3) = 0 Then
        countNumbers = Mid(Cell, 4, 2)
    ElseIf Left(Cell, 2) = 0 Then
        countNumbers = Mid(Cell, 3, 3)
    ElseIf Left(Cell, 1) = 0 Then
        countNumbers = Mid(Cell, 2, 4)
    ElseIf IsNumeric(Left(Cell, 1)) And InStr(Left(Cell, 3), "-") Then
        countNumbers = "000" & Left(Cell, 2)
    ElseIf IsNumeric(Left(Cell, 1)) And InStr(Left(Cell, 4), "-") Then
        countNumbers = "00" & Left(Cell, 3)
    ElseIf IsNumeric(Left(Cell, 1)) And InStr(Left(Cell, 5), "-") Then
        countNumbers = "0" & Left(Cell, 4)
    ElseIf IsNumeric(Left(Cell, 1)) And InStr(Left(Cell, 6), "-") Then
        countNumbers = "0" & Left(Cell, 5)
    ElseIf IsNumeric(Left(Cell, 1)) Then
        countNumbers = Left(Cell, 10)
    Else
        countNumbers = Trim(Left(Cell, 3) & " " & Right(Cell, 3))
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your `FixItUp` sub, change this line:

```
cell.Value = "=Clean_Zip(cell.Value)"
```

to this:

```
Cell.Formula = "=Clean_Zip(""" & Cell.Value & """)"
```

Alternatively it might be nice to process the data and overwrite the value all in one simple sub, rather than using the custom function... here's an example:

```
Sub FixItUpV2()

    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim rng As Range, ZipCode As Range

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("F5:F" & LastRow)

    For Each ZipCode In rng
        'Change cell format to text:
        ZipCode.NumberFormat = "@"
        'Split original value on its hyphen, keep the first segment, and format with a 5 digit mask:
        ZipCode = Format(Split(Trim(ZipCode), "-")(0), "00000")
    Next ZipCode

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help. As a novice coder I still have a lot to learn about VBA..

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better approach using TextToColumns.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FixItUp()

    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range(.Cells(5, "F"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                           TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                           Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
                           Other:=True, OtherChar:="-", _
                           FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, xlGeneralFormat), Array(2, xlSkipColumn))
            .NumberFormat = "00000"
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=F5<=99")
                .NumberFormat = "\E\r\r\o\r"
                .Interior.Color = vbRed
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

The malformed zips will retain their original values while displaying Error on a red background.